# Find the conditional expectation in the following setting

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, lsmeans

Given:

$X_{i} = \Theta +W_{i}$

$\Theta \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma_{0}^2)$

$W_{i} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_{i}^2)$

$\Theta, W_{i}$ are all independent

I need to find the least mean squared estimation for $\Theta$. That would be $E[\Theta \mid X_{1},X_{2},...x_{n}]$

My attempt:
We can infer that

$X_{i} \sim N(\mu, \sigma_{i}^2+\sigma_{0}^2)$

$X_{i}\mid \Theta \sim \mathcal{N}(\Theta, \sigma_{i}^2)$

from here I try to use the bayes equation to find $P(\Theta \mid X)$

$P(\Theta \mid X_{i}) = \frac{P(X_{i}\mid\Theta)P(\Theta)}{P(X_{i})}$

From here I get into the weeds of writing the normal distribution equations and solving and can never come out of them. Am I doing it right? Is the approach accurate and it is just the algebraic manipulation that I am failing at? Or, do I need to try some other approach?

Comment: No, the $X_i$'s have to be considered all at once.

Comment: If I can condition one by one, I would have eventually conditioned upon all Xs. But, if conditioning on all at once is easier then can you please guide me how to do it

Comment: Hi: just think of it a standard regression where the design matrix is a vector of ones. You called the response $X_{i}$ but you can think of it as  the $Y_{i}$ response in a regression. No need for bayesian machinery.